# Join the strings with the other strings

Tags: php, session

I am working on my code to set up the string for my name and email address using the variable. I have got a problem with getting the strings to join, because it wont allow me to use `<` unless I have to use the space and I tried to use `str_replace` to remove the space, but it will still display my name without the email address.

When I try this:

```
$email = $_SESSION["firstname"] . ' <' . $_SESSION["email"] . '>';
```

This is only works so far:

```
$email = $_SESSION["firstname"] . ' < ' . $_SESSION["email"] . ' >';
```

Here is the full code:

```
<?php
    $email = $_SESSION["firstname"] . ' < ' . $_SESSION["email"] . ' >';
    echo $email;
    $html = '<form method="post" action="">
    <select name="emails" id="emails" value="" style="width:300px; height: 26px; margin-top: 10px; onchange="this.form.submit();" method="post">';
    $values = array('unknown', $email);

    foreach($values as $v)
    {
        $selected = '';
        if($v == 'unknown')
        {
           $title = '';
        }else{
           $title = $v;
        }

        if($v == $_SESSION["from"])
        {
           $selected = "selected";
        }
        $html .= "<option $selected value='$v'>$title</option>";
    }
    $html .= "</form>
        </select>";
    echo $html;
?>
```

What it will show like this with a space:

```
Rob < robemail@gmail.com >
```

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
Rob <robemail@gmail.com>
```

I want to display my name and email address to come together with the `<` and `>` so I want to output them in the select options.

Can you please show me an example how I could use to get the strings to join together to display with my name and email address to make it to show like `Rob <robemail@gmail.com>`?

Thank you.

Comment: Remove the spaces.

Comment: I have try it and it dont work. It will only show my name `Rob`. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&lt;` and `&gt;` instead, the **<** or **>** is recognized as HTML tag

Comment: Thank you very much for this as this is what I am looking for exactly. Problem are now solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

`<` and `>` are being recognized as HTML tag.

You could use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function to escape it.

```
<?php
    echo htmlspecialchars($email);
?>
```